# Why is "Region and Language" missing from the `gnome-control-center`?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, locale

I'm a sysadmin charged with maintaining user accounts on a Ubuntu 18.04 system. All of these unprivileged users use Gnome as their primary desktop manager, but none of them are able to change their own keymap. When such a user runs `gnome-control-center`, the window is missing any mention of locales or keymaps, like so:

[image]

How can I allow unprivileged users to change their own keyboard settings?

Edit: adding screenshot of "Languge Support" (`gnome-language-selector`)

[image]

Edit the second: adding information about the status of packages `language-selector-gnome` and `gnome-control-center`:

```
$ echo && date -uIseconds && lsb_release --all && apt-cache policy language-selector-gnome gnome-control-center

2020-08-13T16:38:21+00:00
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
language-selector-gnome:
  Installed: 0.188.3
  Candidate: 0.188.3
  Version table:
 *** 0.188.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.188 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
gnome-control-center:
  Installed: 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6
  Candidate: 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.28.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Edit the third: by popular request, the list of packages (and globs thereof) I previously purged from the system:

```
aisleriot
cheese
firefox
gnome-games
gnome-initial-setup
gnome-mahjongg
gnome-mines
gnome-sudoku
libreoffice*
remmina*
rhythmbox
shotwell*
simple-scan
thunderbird
transmission*
unity-webapps-common
```

Comment: I just created a normal user and tried.. It is working as expected.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/df8Sx.png

Comment: How is the screenshot related to the question?

Comment: Hi @GunnarHjalmarsson "own keyboard settings?" as the OP mentioned, am I wrong? please correct me..

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson , it's related in that the `gnome-control-center` usually allows the user to change one's keymap and/or locale. If you have a better way of accomplishing this, then I would appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @UnKNOWn , that's interesting --- you must have some package and/or configuration that I lack.

Comment: when your user search for `Region & Language` in settings? whats happening?

Comment: @UnKNOWn that search leads me to "Language Support"; clicking on it launches `gnome-language-selector` which also lacks any mention of keymaps.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Yes, the OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and the keymap/locale is the default (I think); i.e., US english or whatever is assigned as defaults during the installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111764/discussion-between-rubicks-and-unknown).

Comment: @rubicks: `gnome-control-center` is indeed the right package, but I would go to _Region & Language_ and look at the _Input Sources_ section rather than _Details -> Date & Time_.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I don't see "Input Sources" in the `gnome-language-selector` window.

Comment: @rubicks: I didn't mean `gnome-language-selector`, I was talking about _Settings -> Region & Language_ in `gnome-control-center`.

Answer (score 1):

tldr; this makes the "Region & Language" tab magically appear:

```
$ gnome-control-center region
```

Thereafter, every subsequent invocation of the `gnome-control-center` pops up with the region tab present and highlighted. I'll update this answer if I can explain what happened.